# Using a related model attribute to return objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an object `Item` that can be one of an `ItemType`.  The `ItemType` has an `attribute` which is either `true` or `false`.

```
Class Item
  belongs_to :item_type
end

Class ItemType
  has_many :items
end
```

At the moment, I am just grabbing the last `x` objects in the usual way:

```
latest_items = Item.last(x)
```

Now, I need to return a list of `x` `Items` where the `ItemType` has an `attribute` set to `true`, something like this (pseudocode):

```
latest_items = Item.last(x).where(Item.item_type.attribute = "true")
```

Is this easily achievable in Rails?  It seems like it should be straight forward, but I'm scrabbling around, unable to find the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily by using

```
latest_items = Item.joins(:item_type).where("item_type.attribute = ?", true).limit(x).order('id desc')
```